# Why isn't this jquery and css consistent across html tables?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, html-table

I have the following jquery code and :

```
$("table.altRow > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("oddColor");
$("table.altRow > tbody > tr:even").addClass("evenColor");
```

and the following css:

```
.altRow tbody tr.evenColor { background-color : #e9e9e9; }
.altRow tbody tr.oddColor { background-color : #ffffff; }
```

and it seems to render inconsistent results

some tables have "evenColor" on the class in the first body TR and others have "oddColor" added as a class to the first body TR.

Any reason why this wouldn't be consistent?  I would like the white (#ffffff) row to always be first body row backcolor

If I have two tables on a single page.  One puts evenColor on the first row of one and the other table had oddColor as the class of the first row of the other table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just wondering, but why are you not using CSS pseudo selectors, like `.altRow tbody tr:nthchild(even)`, does it still give the same issue then?

Comment: Can you show your relevant (minimal/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML? And, if possible, a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo for us to work with?

Comment: Perhaps jQuery sees the first row as "0" (even) whereas CSS see's it as "1" (odd)?

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, I was correct as you can see in this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qV9nx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because jQuery's [`:odd` and `:even` selectors](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) apply to the **list of all selected elements**, regardless of their position in their contexts.

If you want to use jQuery, use [`:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) instead, this way:

```
$(".altRow tbody tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("oddColor");
$(".altRow tbody tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("evenColor");
```

## Performance tips

1. Simplify your selectors, they don't need to be that long. If you apply the class `altRow` to the `<tbody>` you can use selectors like `.altRow tr:nth-child(even)`
2. Use only CSS, without jQuery:

   ```
   .altRow tr { background-color : #e9e9e9; } 
   .altRow tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color : #ffffff; }
   ```

   In IE8-, `:nth-child` is only supported by using [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) or similar libraries.

Comment: Yes, it works in **jQuery selectors** in IE8. It works in **CSS selectors** as well if you add Selectivizr to the page

Comment: Another performance tip would be to just have one instead of two `:nth-child` selectors. So, `tr { color: #e9e9e9 }` and `tr:nth-child(odd) { color: #fff }`.

Comment: Note: They can use that selector even if they don't apply that class to TBODY. The space in the selector denotes ancestry, not a strict parent-child relation.

Comment: @leora Do it with CSS and if you insist provide the jQuery solution as a backup for IE8, loaded via conditional comments specifically for IE8. Don't make modern browsers perform bad because of IE8. Think about mobile (where speeds are x10 slower).

Comment: You're right @ŠimeVidas! You can just one `:nth-child()`, I updated the answer. But there's no need to add the jQuery version, just use Selectivizr and it will take care of itself.

Comment: @bfred.it Yup. Looks good. CSS + Selectivizr seems to be the best solution.

Comment: @bfred it - how much of a performance difference does it really make between the items listed?

Comment: @leora performance is very relative. In Chrome on a modern computer, the difference is barely relevant. The problem with web performance lays with *the amount* of these small things and the device. When you start having thousands of "barely noticeable performance losses" on a complex page on a phone or in IE8, you will **feel** the page lag behind and probably any millisecond saved improves the experience. I wouldn't spend time optimizing selectors on old websites, but if you're writing them now, why use *a slower (and longer to write) version?*

Answer (score 0):

`:odd` selects the elements, not in respective to their parents (as in the nth tr within its table), but within the DOM as a whole.

If you want an example, take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/PGdMz/

And if you don't understand, read this excerpt from jQuery's website:

```
In particular, note that the 0-based indexing means that, counter-intuitively, :odd selects the second element, fourth element, and so on within the matched set.
```

So what you should do, is write this:

```
$("table.altRow > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("oddColor");
$("table.altRow > tbody > tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("evenColor");
```

And if I update that in the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/PGdMz/1/

Comment: that is because IE8 doesn't support this